# Live USB ubuntu on a 2 partitions

Tags: 18.04, live-usb

Can I burn ubuntu distro iso as a live USB to 2 partitions USB. Because I need encrypted live USB using **LUKS**.

After searching i found the **grub** can decrypt encrypted partition by **LUKS**

1. first partition for **/boot**
2. secound partition for **filesystem** like /root /home /casper

Comment: Why would you wish to do this?

Comment: @user535733 I want to create a luks partition to encrypt file system

Comment: Then you cannot use a Live image. You must *install* Ubuntu onto a USB stick in order to use encryption.

Comment: You only encrypt files you **need** to encrypt, eg if someone should steal your drive which has **sensitive data** on it which could compromise you personally or make you poorer financially. There is absolutely no point in encrypting a live Ubuntu USB.

Comment: Have a look at [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2424061).

Comment: Encrypted Full install to USB that boots BIOS or UEFI: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086309/how-to-make-bios-uefi-flash-drive-with-full-disk-encryption/1086314#1086314

Answer (score 0):

Because LUKS will not work with a LiveUSB, you must install Ubuntu from a LiveUSB (or other media) to a second LiveUSB. Boot from the first USB, the LiveUSB, then with the second USB plugged in, start installing Ubuntu. When it asks where to install it, specify the second USB drive.