# Legacy boot with full disk encryption

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, live-usb, encryption

I've been following the steps outlined in the following questions / tutorials.

Paddy Landau's Manual Full System Encryption:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2399092

C.S.Cameron addition:

[How to Make BIOS/UEFI Flash Drive with Full Disk Encryption](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086309/how-to-make-bios-uefi-flash-drive-with-full-disk-encryption)

I am able to create a live disk using the method outlined on the askubuntu link and it does boot UEFI with full encryption.

At first UEFI boot, I performed this step:

> Now mount the ESP boot partition and copy ESP/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg and
> overwrite ESP/boot/grub/grub.cfg.

I did this and ran update-grub and update-grub2 and then rebooted the system.

The problem is that it does not boot legacy, only UEFI.
When attempting to boot legacy, it loads the grub> menu.

Attempting to use ls or search, returns

```
error: file '/EFI/ubuntu/grub/i386-pc/ls.mod' not found.
```

grub shows these values set:

```
prefix=(hd0,gpt3)/EFI/ubuntu/grub
root=hd0,gpt3
```

When booted with UEFI and EFI partition is mounted,
I can see the EFI folder listed about.

My EFI partition is 3 and this is the only drive, so the prefix and root should be correct.

Results of `fdisk -l` :

[image: Screenshot of fdisk -l output]

GParted:

[image: Gparted]

Also, as seen in the fdisk, I do have an error within fdisk.
This error was not initially present after creating the partitions with mkusb.

```
The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
```