# Bootable 16.04 LTS with Luks encryption on a single hdd

Tags: boot, 16.04, partitioning, encryption, luks

I currently have 16.04 LTS running off a usb on an external hdd. using bios boot menu I boot from usb and use ubuntu from the hdd. I can take this between machines and boot into it. But now I need that same setup but encrypted as I may potentially have data on it needing some protection. It can only be 16.04 LTS.

I want Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my hdd as the only OS on it, and have it encrypted with Luks so it takes one inputted password after I have booted to the usb hdd to use the OS. I don't hibernate but for virtual memory I believe it is important still to have a swap partition and for that to be encrypted too. So I believe I need LVM on Luks to organise this.

I keep finding guides for newer versions of Ubuntu or they want the unencrypted boot part (GRUB I think) on a different device "for security". I'm not very familiar with the tools so I'm not sure what to change from these tutorials to achieve what I want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Make BIOS/UEFI Flash Drive with Full Disk Encryption](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086309/how-to-make-bios-uefi-flash-drive-with-full-disk-encryption)

Answer (score 1):

### If you want Full Disk Encryption start with a Full install to USB

- Unplug your internal drives so that they do not get overwritten.
- Boot Live Ubuntu installer USB.
- Plug in Target USB drive.
- Start Install Ubuntu.
- When you get to "Installation type' select Erase disk and Install Ubuntu, Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation..., Use LVM with the new Ubuntu installation.
- Complete the installation.

Another method if you want an encrypted drive that will work on both BIOS and UEFI computers: [How to Make BIOS/UEFI Flash Drive with Full Disk Encryption](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086309/how-to-make-bios-uefi-flash-drive-with-full-disk-encryption)