# Ubuntu Installation type won't select Disk2?

Tags: boot, 20.04, system-installation, usb, usb-installation

**Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS jammy** is running a bootable USB1 with ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso.

Installing ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64 to Disk2 won't progress at the Install menu Installation type?

Disk2 is selected as `/dev/sdb` with 120 GB free space and Device for boot loader installation: `/dev/sdb` Disk2 (120 GB) is selected.

My CPU is Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-10105F CPU @ 3.70GHz, but the Ubuntu amd64 shouldn't make a difference?

However the Install Now button is greyed out?

Also, not sure why there's 2 fields to select Disk2 in the top and bottom fields?

[image: SSD with 120GB]

[image: SSD formatted to default settings from Disks app]

I think I need to fully disclose the [aim of this step](https://xyproblem.info/).

Basically a fresh Ubuntu OS with default network settings, with no Internet and then installing a KVM router for Internet.
OS1 (Ubuntu) with Internet on Disk1 (SSD 240GB):

1. Write `ubuntu.iso` to USB1 as a bootable usb.
2. Boot from USB1. In the installer, select Disk2 (SSD2 120GB, minimum 25GB) as the installation target
3. Boot from Disk2. Install virt-manager. I'm still in MY place where I HAVE Internet. So I just ‘apt install virt-manager’.
4. go to the target (Disk1), and clone Disk2 to the target hard disk (Disk1).
   `sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sda bs=4M status=progress`  Replace sdb with the Disk2 device, and sda with the Disk1 device.
5. Install `pfSense.iso` from USB3.
6. Setup Internet with KVM bridging or passthrough NICs to pfSense.

Comment: A workaround is described at [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692). Please read the whole thread before starting to use it. - Install a compressed image of Ubuntu Server 22.04 'Jammy' and after that install the desktop environment that you want. Installing the meta package `ubuntu-desktop` brings standard Ubuntu Desktop. You may prefer a lighter flavour and use `lubuntu-desktop` or `xubuntu-desktop` to get Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

Comment: There are also other ways to install Ubuntu onto a USB drive, for example according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step), that will help you use your iso file.

Comment: Did you click on new partition table and create ESP & / (root) partitions? Or use gparted to create partitions first? Be sure to use gpt not MBR(msdos).

Comment: I have just used Ubuntu's app Disks, to format Disk2 with default settings.

Comment: See [this question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260830/create-encrypted-bootable-usb-without-overwriting-internal-disk/1331004#1331004) for installing Ubuntu on an USB using Virtual Machine manager.

Comment: Solved. (I can't answer my own question due to StackExchange limitations). 1. Formatted Disk2 with Ext4, using Ubuntu app Disks;
 2. Cleaned Disk2 of any bugs, using Terminal$ sudo gdisk /dev/sdb > select "o" > select "w";
 3. Checked Disk2 was mounted, using Terminal$ sudo partprobe /dev/sdb;
 4. Ran installer from USB1;
 5. Added partitions: efi 512 MB, swap 8196 MB and remaining storage as ext4 mounting to /;
 6. selected boot loader /dev/sdb1 (needs to be set to what the efi partition is);
 7. selected Install Now.

Comment: @user1416486, Maybe you have enough 'points' now to answer your own question. Maybe you must wait for one or two days, and then try to write the answer. -- Anyway, an 'answer' would make it possible to make your description of the solution much easier to read because there are much better editing tools available for an 'answer' compared to a 'comment'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

1. Formatted Disk2 to Ext4, using Ubuntu's Disks app;
2. Cleaned Disk2 of any bugs with command
   `$ sudo gdisk /dev/sdb` -> select "o" -> select "w";
3. Checked Disk2 was mounted with command `$ sudo partprobe /dev/sdb`;
4. Ran installer from USB1;
5. Added partitions: efi 512 MB, swap 8196 MB and remaining storage as ext4 mounting to `/`;
6. Selected boot loader `/dev/sdb1` (needs to be set to what the efi partition is);
7. Selected Install Now.

Answer (score -1):

**If you want to install ubuntu**
referring from [Ubuntu official]{https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop}

> Recommended system requirements:

> **25 GB** of free hard drive space

If you want to install Ubuntu on SSD then choose new partition table.

**If you want to install GRUB bootloader**
installing GRUB on usb stick doesn't make any sense since the bootloader executes first to make able to acces to your OS which is ubuntu in this case.

Bootloaders generaly are installed in the first partition of the drive with EFI formating, in your case its `/dev/sda1`, assuming you want to dual boot with another ubuntu entry, no need to install a bootloader since you can configure the first one to detect both OS.
hope this was helpful.