# Ubuntu 22.04 encryption disk, acces by usb key

Tags: usb, login, 22.04, encryption

it is possible to make a usb key who login me automatically in to encrypted Ubuntu?

Comment: You can make a bootable USB that has encrypted Ubuntu running on it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086309/how-to-make-bios-uefi-flash-drive-with-full-disk-encryption/1330970#1330970

Comment: @C.S.Cameron thanks a lot bro! :)